# Android - cleaned project, R file will not regenerate

Tags: android

Help, I'm occasionally encountered this randomly with Android, but this time seems pervasive and I want to know how to fix this once and for all - in this situation

I cleaned my project because I added a new ID and reference in the XML and a new drawable asset, yet the project was giving an error on the ID reference (so this is why I cleaned it).

Now the R file isn't recognized, and it doesn't regenerate when I clean the project, or close the project, or close/open eclipse

R cannot be resolved to variable, now I can't compile, le sigh

solutions and pinpoint the cause of this problem?

Comment: Not for this project, although I do have timemachine available, rolling back doesn't really illuminate the cause though

Comment: Right, rolling back doesn't. But "Show Changes" or comparing differences in files would.

Comment: delete old R.java and create manually R.java and then refresh the project or clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to check the console for this one. It had an issue with an image named "default.png"

apparently you can't use default.png for drawable names.

that combined with R file won't compile if you have XML errors (saw that answer in another stack exchange, so it helped me look for things)